# create a trigger to update status on parent table based on values of child table

Tags: postgresql, trigger, rdbms

```
Table order 
columns - id  status
           1  confirmed 

Table trays
columns - id,orderid(fk),status
           1   1        done
           2   1        processing
```

I have to update the status of order table to finished only after all the elements of trays related to the particular order are done eg. one order has two trays once the status of both trays changed to done then i  need to update the status of order to finished. is there anyway to handle this scenario with afterupdate trigger ? Thanks in advance

Comment: Please have a look at: [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2990/minimal-complete-and-verifiable-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you need in this:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER fix_order_status
AFTER UPDATE
ON trays
FOR EACH ROW
UPDATE order
SET order.status = 'confirmed'
WHERE order.id = NEW.orderid
  AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
                   FROM trays
                   WHERE trays.orderid = NEW.orderid
                     AND trays.status <> 'done' );
```

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=94da7a5b75baa8200f36c319f6b0b662)

Comment: The status of trays can be multiple options like loaded,unloaded but when both turns out be  done then i need to update the orderstatus is it possible to make some case conditions ? @Akina

Comment: @ManojSelvam *The status of trays can be multiple options like loaded,unloaded* ... and all of them are not equal to 'done', is it? so what's wrong? DEMO fiddle added.

Comment: Thanks @akina  The error occured because postgres doesnt recognised tablename.column (order.status) after the set. when I changed to only column name everything worked as expected